# Issues with DollarSigns and StartsWith() java

Tags: java, regex, startswith

I have searched through-fully all the sides of Stackoverflow and Google, and found nothing to help my problem.

Why is it that this code:

```
if((w.startsWith("\\$", 0) || (w.startsWith("\\$", 1))){
}
```

and this:

```
if((w.charAt(0) == '$') || (w.charAt(1) == '$' && w.charAt(0) == ' ')){
}
```

and this:

```
 if((w.startsWith("\\$") || (w.startsWith(" \\$"))){
 }
```

Does not work?

I'm trying to test if a string starts with a dollar sign, or a space and a dollar sign, but for some ODD reason, I can't seem to find the problem related to the "starts with space" part.

Because the charAt(0) == '$' works just fine... but if I want to test if it starts with a space, then followed by a dollar sign, it doesn't work.

There are no errors... just nothing happens. Any guidelines/fixes would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to escape the `$` as `String.startsWith` takes just a normal string as argument, not a regex.

```
if (w.startsWith("$") || w.startsWith(" $"))
```

will suffice.

If you use `String.startsWith(String prefix, int offset)` (not required in this case I think) give `0` as offset, not 1 as you have to check from the beginning for a `$`. It is required if you have to test whether a substring starts with the prefix. In that case, give the beginIndex of substring.

Comment: OMG thank you lol. And btw, it wasn't even this that didnt work lol my regex was wrongly escaped... but thanks for cleaning up my code :P

Comment: @Zacky1 the argument required for `startsWith` function is not regex. Only in the case of regex, you need to escape a `$`

Comment: I have done so, stackoverflow didn't let me accept it for some reason D:

Answer (score 0):

Just do the two `startsWith` expressions without escaping:

```
if (w.startsWith("$") || w.startsWith(" $")) {...}
```

Comment: Should just do `if(w.trim().startsWith("$")) {...}` That way it will work with any amount of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Just `trim` it. It removes whitespace before and after.

```
if(w.trim().charAt(0) == '$') {
  ...
}
```

Comment: `trim()` removes all spaces in the string and the requirement is to check whether it begins with **a** space followed by `$`

Comment: trim only takes spaces off of the beginning and the end, none in the middle. making "\t hello world! \t\t" into "hello world!" He never said he needed to *only* test the case with one space.

Comment: He tried `w.charAt(1) == '$' && w.charAt(0) == ' '` which means he has to match ` $` and not `  $`.

Comment: I meant he required to match `a space followed by $` and not `two spaces followed by $`

Comment: in what case would you want to match a single space and not a double space or a tab?

Comment: i don't know the context. I said so based on the code he tried.